# php spl_autoload not loading the class

Tags: php, autoload

I am facing a weird problem, the below function works fine when I was testing it in a Windows system, but the same function is unable to the load class when I am using it in Ubuntu 12.04.

Below in my function, the commented **include** loads the function , but **spl_autoload()** does not load the class. I am confused as to what might be the reason.

```
public function controller($class)
{
    $class = preg_replace('/Controller$/ui','',$class);
    ini_get('include_path');
    set_include_path(CONTROLLER_DIR.lcfirst($class).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    spl_autoload_extensions('Controller.php');
    #include(get_include_path().$class.spl_autoload_extensions()); # <-----This works fine
    spl_autoload($class); # <----but this is not loading the class
}
```

Any thoughts?..

Comment: Why are you doing `ini_get('include_path');` if you're not using the result of it?

Comment: @scragar yup , I put it , just thought this might resolve the error !

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having a hard time visualizing your directory structure given this extract of code.. Could you make an ASCII layout showing what the directory structure looks like, and a class that you would like to load?

Comment: @charmeleon strange somewhat I figured it out , spl_autoload is loading the class with file name starting from lowercase !! gonna dig my head some more into it .